# Javascript (if var contains a word, change that word colour ONLY)

Tags: javascript

Basically the idea behind this is to point out key words from program code from a variable (linked to a SQL SERVER, and the column being a VARCHAR(MAX))

This is the code im trying to implement which changes the whole string to Blue, as it contains the word 'if':

```
if (contentItem.screen.SoftwareLibrary.Code.indexOf(if) !== 1) {
    element.style.color = "blue";
}
```

what I would like to happen is it scans through the variable Code, and it contains the word 'if', I want that word only to turn blue.

is this possible? and thankyou for any pointers or help

Comment: JS variables don't have colors. How are you showing the text? What is `.Code`? What is `element`?

Comment: Are you trying to colorize source code? If so, you should check out this: https://highlightjs.org/ It supports a variety of languages and is customizable via CSS themes for each language.

Comment: yes I am basically, key words I would like to stand out and colorizing them is useful in all programming languages I use... I look into it now, thanks for the help, the text is being shown in a Lightswitch application in a varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go the highlight.js route, you can use something like the following:

```
contentItem.screen.SoftwareLibrary.Code.replace("if", "<span style=\"color:blue\">if</span>");
//... other color rules  
element.innerHTML = contentItem.screen.SoftwareLibrary.Code;
```

I would highly recommend using highlight.js though as it is very robust and would save lots of time.

Comment: im looking at tge highlight.js at the moment as your very right, it would take forever

Comment: the code changes the layout but does nothing with the colours, however I didn't know about highlight.js so ill try this, thankyou

Comment: Ah, I guess I don't have enough context to give the exact code for colorizing, but I'm glad you'll be able to give highlight.js a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use **replace()** method, try the following:

```
contentItem.screen.SoftwareLibrary.Code.replace("if", "<span style=\"background-color:red\">if</span>");
```

Or you can create a CSS class `colored` and give it a different background color, and whenever you find the word if you give it this class:

**CSS:**

```
.colored {
   background-color:red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
//managethuis function like you want
window.addEventListener("load", changeColor);

 function changeColor() {
   contentItem.screen.SoftwareLibrary.Code.replace("if", "<span class=\"colored\">if</span>");
 }
```

Comment: im afraid nothing happens, ive made sure the case is correct aswell and the general text field remains black

Comment: This code will work, but you have to apply any color changes before updating the DOM. Otherwise, it will not update the color and the text will remain the default color.

Comment: Or you can make a CSS class `colored` and give it a different color and give your word this class, take a look at my EDIT.